# mid point using reverse iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

palindromes implementation using reverse iterators

the error in code is of "operator /", is not defined for iterators

```
bool isPalindrome( std::string & s)
{
    bool check = ( s == std::string{ s.rbegin(), s.rend() } );
    return check;    // works fine
}
```

in above there are n comparisons. (  `n=s.length` )

```
s == string{ s.rbegin(), s.rbegin() + (s.rend()/2) } 
         /* error: operator/ not defined */
```

I'm expecting a one or two lines of code for palindrome check with `floor(n/2)` comparisons.
Is there an elegant code. Am I missing something about reverse iterators?

and input of `std::string{"cac"}` should return true and should require 1 comparison

How to get mid-point in O(1) time, using reverse iterators

Comment: Distances between iterators are integers (and you can do division on integers), but iterators are not divisible by anything...

Comment: If you want to improve performance for the polyndrome check then you'd better make a simple for-loop check, instead of instantiating a new string (it allocates data and copies the string into it - a complete waste of time).

Answer (score 3):

Dividing an iterator by a number does not really make sense. What you can do is obtain an iterator that is advanced half way the length of the container like this:

```
string{s.rbegin(), std::next(s.rbegin(), s.size() / 2)}
```

[std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) obtains the iterator after incrementing it the supplied number of times.

This is only going to be efficient `O(1)` for contiguous containers like `std::vector`, `std::array` and `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing something that references an element with the index of that element. Just think about what `s.rend()/2` is supposed to mean. What you actually want is some difference between two indices divided by 2.

Given two iterators you can get their distance via [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: s == string{s.rbegin(), s.rbegin()+( distance(s.begin(),s.end())/2 ) } seems to not work

Comment: @inconspicuous please try to be more specific. You should have included the error message already in the question btw (together with a [mcve])

Comment: @inconspicuous `string{s.rbegin(), s.rbegin()+( distance(s.begin(),s.end())/2 ) }` applied to string "abc" will yield string "c", if you wanted "cb" you ought to adjust it a bit depending on parity of the length of the string.